# ExtJs - keep grid row selected while edit

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I change the value of the `id` column in my grid by listening to `change` of a textfield:

```
oTextfieldName.on( 'change', function( oField, strValue ) {
   oStore.getAt( 0 ).setId( strValue );
}
```

However, if `setId()` is called, the selection of that row `0` is removed. My app is dependent on that selected row to stay selected.

How can I keep the row selected, while still editing/changing that id column?

---

Edit:

When using `store.sync()` it gets back selected.

However, my store gets messed up throwing:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object function () {
            this.destroy = Ext.emptyFn;
        } has no method 'indexOf' ext-dev.js:1253`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `sync()` led to this error, I now use that poor way:

```
oSelectionModel.deselect( nIndex, true );        
oSelectionModel.select( nIndex, true );
```

After changing, I deselect (which is luckily invisible) and then select. At least it works.

Answer (score 2):

Can you just re-select the row?

```
oTextfieldName.on( 'change', function( oField, strValue ) {
   oStore.getAt( 0 ).setId( strValue );
   yourGrid.getSelectionModel().select(0);
}
```

You could also do something like this to suppress the selection event from firing.

```
var suppressEvent = true;
yourGrid.getSelectionModel().select(rowIndex, null, suppressEvent);
```

Check out the docs for the [SelectionModel select method](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.selection.Model-method-select)

Here is a simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cfzFZ/7/) you can play with.  If you click the "Test" button it will select the row at index 1.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that, didnt work. I still have no clue how to get that edit state back to normal. See my edit.